# How to retrieve first 2 results from mysql array without querying again?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Each page lists all the coupons available for a specific retailer. I query the database for all the coupon codes in the header since I count the number of rows returned and use that info in the meta title of the page. I now also want to display the titles of the first 2 coupons in the array. How would I go about extracting the first 2 results from the array without querying the database again?

This is what I have so far:

```
$retailer_coupons = "select C.couponid,C.fmtc_couponid,C.merchantid,C.exclusive,C.label,C.shoppingtip,C.restrictions,C.coupon,C.custom_order,C.link,C.image,C.expire,C.unknown,M.name,M.approved,M.homepageurl,M.category from tblCoupons C,tblMerchants M where C.merchantid=M.merchantid and C.begin <  ".mktime()." and C.expire > ".mktime()." and C.merchantid=".$merchantid." and M.display='1' and C.user_submitted='' order by C.custom_order desc, C.coupon desc";
$retailer_coupons_result = mysql_query($retailer_coupons) or die(mysql_error());
$count_coupons=mysql_num_rows($retailer_coupons_result);
$meta_title = ''.$name.' Coupon Codes ('.$count_coupons.' coupons available)';
```

Comment: [`or die()` must die](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die). Also, what do you mean by *querying the database again*? You haven't fetched any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I have 3 records in my table. If I execute below query, I will get `2` results however the `count(*)` will give me `3` as output

`SELECT count(*) FROM temp.maxID limit 2`

In your case it will be

```
$retailer_coupons =
    "select C.couponid,C.fmtc_couponid,C.merchantid,C.exclusive,C.label,C.shoppingtip,C.restrictions,C.coupon,C.custom_order,C.link,C.image,C.expire,C.unknown,M.name,M.approved,M.homepageurl,M.category
    from tblCoupons C,tblMerchants M
    where C.merchantid=M.merchantid
    and C.begin <  ".mktime()." and C.expire > ".mktime()."
    and C.merchantid=".$merchantid." and M.display='1'
    and C.user_submitted=''
    order by C.custom_order desc, C.coupon desc
    limit 2";
```

`limit 2` will do the magic... Cheers!!!

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I tried your code but it isn't working. I think the count(*) is missing from the code you wrote for me? How do I output the total count as a php variable? Thanks!!

Comment: `limit 2` will display you only first two records only... If you want to count total number of rows, count(*) will do it...

Could you please update your question and display what will be input and what would be output?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($retailer_coupons_result);
$i = 0;
while ($i < 2){
    echo $res[$i]['label']."\n";
    $i++;
}
```